# How to copy Excel cells for matched value to other workseets?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, office365, excel-online

I'm trying to build a way to track issued access cards. Our access cards are (4) digits in length. I'd like to track the status of the card "Issued, Faulty, Lost, Returned" as well as the date of the status change. Ideally, when someone updates the Card Status to a new status, the "Status, Card Number, and Date" cells would be copied to a separate worksheet named after those statuses. Thank you in advance! Example below with 5 worksheets "Main, Issued, Faulty, Lost, Returned":

**MAIN WORKSHEET**

| Card Status | Employee | Card Number | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Card Issued | John | 1234 | 7/9/2021 |
| Card Faulty | Paul | 1235 | 7/9/2021 |
| Card Lost | Ringo | 1236 | 7/9/2021 |
| Card Returned | George | 1237 | 7/9/2021 |

**Card Issued Worksheet**

| Card Status | Employee | Card Number | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Card Issued | John | 1234 | 7/9/2021 |

**Card Faulty Worksheet**

| Card Status | Employee | Card Number | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Card Faulty | Paul | 1235 | 7/9/2021 |

**Card Lost Worksheet**

| Card Status | Employee | Card Number | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Card Lost | Ringo | 1236 | 7/9/2021 |

**Card Returned Worksheet**

| Card Status | Employee | Card Number | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Card Returned | George | 1237 | 7/9/2021 |

Comment: Can you please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68319595/edit) to let us konw what you've tried and where the problem is?

Comment: I'm not sure where to even start to be honest. I have built the worksheets already, but can't figure out the right formula to give me the action I want of copying the data from the "main Worksheet" to the other worksheets and then auto updating those worksheets as the status change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The FILTER function should work for Excel 365 for Web. Here is an example for the Card Issued worksheet:

```
=FILTER(CardStatusTable,CardStatusTable[Card Status]="Card Issued")
```

You put the body of the card status table into the "array" part of the function. Then put the column that contains the card status into the "include" part and test to see if it is equal to "Card Issued", "Card Faulty", etc.

[image: example]

Reference: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/filter-function-f4f7cb66-82eb-4767-8f7c-4877ad80c759

Comment: This worked perfectly! Unfortunately, I can't vote on it. The article you linked was very helpful. Thank you!

Comment: @Mike - great. I think you can mark it as the answer, which is all the same.